# count pattern occurrence per line

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk

The desired output keeps for each line the first two 'columns' and adds the number of occurrences of 'word' on that same line.

Input:

```
string1 string2 aaaaaaaaa word aaaaaaaa word  
string3 string4 ccccccccccc word dddaaaaaaacccd word dddddaaaaa word bbbb  
string5 string6 aaaa word bbbbbbaddd word aaaaa word ccccccdddddddddd word cccccc
```

Desired output:

```
string1 string2 2  
string3 string4 3  
string5 string6 4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If line 1 was `string1 string2 aawordaaa word aaaaaaaa word`, would the output count be 2 or 3 for that line? What if `word` appeared as part of string1 or string2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '{print $1,$2,gsub(/word/,"")}' file
string1 string2 2
string3 string4 3
string5 string6 4
```

#### Explanation

- The gsub() function returns the number of substitutions made.

Comment: +1 very clever! You probably want to use `/\<word\>/` to ensure it doesnt count words containing word.

Comment: Nice and simple approach.

Comment: Thank you! This 'gsub' approach is indeed a simple and effective solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'm ignoring [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), here's how to do it with awk:

```
awk '{count=0; 
      for(i=3; i <= NF; i++) {if($i=="word") { count++ }}; 
      print $1, $2, count; }' inputfile
```